# add images to the repeater

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, repeater

i want to display images by using repeater control. those images have to change with respect each 5seconds. how to change those images? those images should be in database? i kept images in my project folder. then now how to go further..please help me..

Thanks,
Mihir

Comment: not sure to see the relation between the repeater and the changing images... For the later point, you will have to do it using some javascript and/or ajax to change the image source on the fly each 5 seconds. The timer must also live at the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use AdRotator Control of Asp.Net http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/AdRotator_VT.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479310.aspx

Comment: @Muhammad..ya thats it.. i dont remember exactly the controller name..thank u for your help dear..